# ruby 2.0 how to access element in matrix by coordinate?

Tags: ruby, matrix

I'm new to ruby, but here is the problem. Say I have a matrix, and I need to modify a element at 1,2

```
mm = Matrix.build(2,4) {0}
mm[1][2] = 404
```

but this will rise error message

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
from /Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/matrix.rb:314:in `[]'
from (irb):11
from /Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I have checked ruby doc, but didn't find any answer, sorry to ask such a stupid question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get element:

```
mm[1,2] #output 0
```

Set element:

No method can do that. Matrix is immutable object and cannot be changed (which is, IMHO, not so optimal). You can either copy the matrix by `each` to an array, change the element, and convert back, or use monkey patch

```
class Matrix
  def []=(i, j, x)
    @rows[i][j] = x
  end
end
mm[1,2] = 404
```

Or if you don't want to monkey patch or want to be a bit hacky (although does not look good):

```
mm.send(:[]=, 1, 2, 404)
```

Comment: I agree, we probably should make matrices mutable.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and the first impression of ruby is it's so simple and elegant, I don't understand why the matrix and multi dimensional arrays are so complicated ...

Comment: Because apparently all the serious math folks use Python. I'm running into this issue myself....

Comment: @Brandon I believe they use R or Matlab